# file_get_contents HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a php script that will return a google search but it gives me the HTTP error.

```
  if (strstr(file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://". $url ."&gws_rd=ssl"), 'did not match any documents.')) 
{
  return "No";
}

else {

    return "Yes";

}
A PHP Error was encountered
```

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://google.com&gws_rd=ssl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Filename: libraries/google_index.php

Line Number: 8

error : HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable.
how can i force this or something so it will get the contents.

Comment: Okay, cool, but I don't see a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an URL as GET parameter of another URL, you must `urlencode()` it. Otherwise, some characters like `?` or `&` will be considered as parts of the main URL.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but actually all of this "http://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://". $url ."&gws_rd=ssl" is part of the main url

Comment: @NorvertJohnAbella Well you still need to encode it. Or you'll get the error you're seeing.

Comment: @NickG yes, i already encode it $string = "http://www.google.com/search?q=site:". urlencode($url) ."&gws_rd=ssl"; but still getting the error

Comment: Perhaps you should post an example URL which isn't working. Does it depend on the value of $url?  Does it do the same thing if you don't search on "site:".... ie if you search on a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the whole URL, like:

```
 $string = "google.com/search?q=site:". urlencode($url ."&gws_rd=ssl")
```